# How to construct Dynamic @Para statement?

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

How to construct dynamic select statement with two different parameters.
My code works fine without parameter but if i like to convert it in parameters.

If i convert code with `@VehiNo` and `@CustName`.
Please check comments in code.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConn))
{
    if (txtSearchVehicleNo.MaskCompleted)
    {
        sqlString = "Select * From Master Where VehiNo = '" + txtSearchVehicleNo.Text + "'";  // here i convert with @VehiNo
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSearchMemberName.Text))
    {
        sqlString = "Select * From Master Where CustName = '" + txtSearchMemberName.Text + "'"; // here i convert with @CustName
    }

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        // How to use following 2 in condition
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VehiNo", txtSearchVehicleNo.Text);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", txtSearchMemberName.Text);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dtMember.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to move `if` statement to `using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn))`

Comment: @MonarchL if i put two set of if-else one above sqlCommand for string and other inside sqlCommand for `cmd.parameters` then its works but i have to use if-else two time. If you know any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConn))
{

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        string sqlString = string.Empty;
        if (txtSearchVehicleNo.MaskCompleted)
        {
            sqlString = "Select * From Master Where VehiNo = @VehiNo;";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VehiNo", txtSearchVehicleNo.Text);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSearchMemberName.Text))
        {
            sqlString = "Select * From Master Where CustName = @CustName;";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", txtSearchMemberName.Text);
        }

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlString;

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dtMember.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that it gives `ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized` error

Comment: I have made few changes. Try again.